# Best practices when building JSF applications that produce elegant user experiences

Tags: jsf, web-applications, primefaces

I'm using PrimaFaces with Mojarra implementation for my JSF applications. When I put together the application I use company/app logos and the primefaces widgets (the widgets themselves look great!) which have the jQuery look and feel. The issue is that the applications end up looking very similar with a somewhat box type appearance - text boxes, datatables etc., The look and feel is nowhere compared to a handcoded   by a html/css designer/developer.

When you develop enterprise JSF applications what are some of the best practices you use to ensure a user-friendly good looking ui?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for but there is a tradeoff between speed of development and appearance. That said, in our shop we use PrimeFaces and have developers who make the page "work". They are then followed on by xhtml/css designers who clean up the appearance of the page and controls. If you haven't already, check out the styling section. There is quite a bit of flexibility in changing the appearance of controls. Of course they are still layered, pre-defined controls.

Edit: You can style individual parts of your controls using css. So for example here we change the appearance of the title bar:

```
.bottomViewItem .ui-panel-titlebar{ 
    background: none;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0.1em 16px 0.2em 0;
}
```

And here we change the title appearance:

```
.bottomViewItem .ui-panel-titlebar span.ui-panel-title{
    color: #E27C4C !important;
    font-family: Rockwell, Georgia, Arial !important;
    font-size: 18px !important;
    margin: 0.1em 16px 0.2em 0;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Let me provide an example to help clarify. In my case, one of the practices I'm taking on is minimizing or skipping widget functions in favor of hand-coded html/css/jQuery when possible. For example, instead of using the title which comes with the panel, coding and styling the title using css. When your developers hand it off to designers, I am guessing they might be adding a good mix of html/css styling.

Comment: Yes, our designers are adding a good bit of css. They are modifying the PF widgets with css, not replacing functionality. I expanded my answer with an example of how we style our panels. It sounds like you are doing the same thing in a different way. The advantage of styling the control is the re-usability of the styling across your application. This allows you to customize the look of the panel and panel title and still use the PF facet. If you want to apply the same look/feel across multiple applications you can even create a theme jar file as described at the end of the PF documentation.